# Inconsistency between sequences and seqiplot

Tags: r, sequence, analysis, traminer

I am using the function seqiplot to create a sequence index plot. The problem is that I get some inconsistencies between what is shown on the plot and my sequence data. For example, I have the same sequence state in period t and t+1; however, the sequence index plot shows different colours for each period. Should not they have the same colour?

I suspect that it has to do with the number of posible states in my data set. There are 60 different states. So when I try to set the colour scheme I get this message:
In brewer.pal(60, "Accent") :
  n too large, allowed maximum for palette Accent is 8
Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors

which indicates that Accent has a maximum of 8 colours (isn't it?).

Has anyone had a similar problem? How can I fix it?

Regards,

Francisco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default color palette used by `TraMineR` can get a maximum of 12 different colors, which is clearly insufficient in your case. Hence, you have to specify the color palette using the `cpal` argument in `seqdef`. The `colorspace` package provides functions to get more than 12 colors.

To choose your 60 colors using a graphical interface:

```
library(colorspace)
pal <- choose_palette()
seqdef(..., cpal=pal)
```

Or to automatically get a list of colors, try

```
library(colorspace)
pal <- diverge_hcl(60)
seqdef(..., cpal=pal)
```

See `?diverge_hcl` for more options.

Hope this helps.